# Does inserting 'had' between 'they' and 'ever' make this sentence correct ? Or there is no error in the sentence

Tags: grammaticality, errors

Organic pulses are so popular today that people wonder how ***they ever*** lived without them.

Comment: Maybe you're on a smartphone, and the [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) is not the first place where you would look or find information about asking questions, but it should be. Unfortunately, your question is explicitly off-topic because it is asking users to proofread (correct your grammar, spelling, punctuation, phrasing, etc.) your text. Please visit the link. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't see any grammatical error in the sentence, "Organic pulses have become so popular today that people wonder how they ever lived without them." What part of the sentence do you have concern about?

Comment: "....wonder how they ever "had " ever lived without them.

Comment: @praveshvats please edit your question and explain why you think your sentence might be incorrect.

Comment: It appears that you have changed your question by editing it to read:  "Does inserting 'had' between 'they' and 'ever' make this sentence correct ? Or there is no error in the sentence?"

The sentence in your original question was already correct and did not need the word, “had,” to be inserted to make it correct.   

“Had” is the PAST PERFECT TENSE and indicates that an action was completed at some point in the past BEFORE something else happened. 

I suggest you leave your original sentence alone. There was nothing wrong with it.